# Rotating a circle around an ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry

Is it possible that we rotate a circle around an ellipse when the distance from the center of the circle to the ellipse is always the same?

I have tried consider the center of the circle $(x_0,y_0)$ as:
$$x_0=(a+R)\cos t,\\
y_0=(b+R) \sin t$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the major and minor semi-axis of the ellipse, respectively, and $R$ is the radius of the circle, for $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Then the center of the circle move on another ellipse with two semi-axis: $(a+R)$ and $(b+R)$

I found out that this is wrong. I was wondering if it is possible to do that.

Comment: If the distance from the center of ellipse to center of circle is always the same, that means that $a=b$ or the ellipse is a circle.

Comment: What is “the distance from the center of the circle to the ellipse”? Do you measure from the circle’s center to the closest point on the ellipse?

Comment: Of course this is possible. Carve an ellipse and a circle out of solid cardboard, and roll one over the other.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar I mean the distance to the ellipse, like the closest point of the ellipse to the center of circle

Comment: @Lubin yes I mean that

Comment: @IvanNeretin I mean mathematically how can I measure the center of the circle when it rotates around the ellipse?

Comment: That can be done too. Take the parametric equation of the ellipse, find the direction of normal at (x,y), step for $R$ in that direction, and you'll have the parametric equation of the trace left by the center of the circle. True, that curve will **not** be an ellipse, despite looking kinda like it.

Comment: Indeed, @IvanNeretin, if you think of a very thin (highly eccentric) ellipse and a circle that’s not too large or too small, you see how very far from elliptical the resulting figure will be.